# Hololens emulator showing NullReferenceException

Tags: hololens, hololens-emulator, windows-mixed-reality

I'm trying to run a Hello World kind of problem for a HoloLens on emulator but it is showing error:

```
The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 
'Connecting to the device '<device>'.': NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object. [0x80004003]
```

I have tried making a new project, reinstalling emulator and checked Hyper-V on my system

Comment: May we see code or some additional information?

Comment: I am just following something similar to this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/hello-world-in-hololens/). What I am basically trying is just the setup. I haven't coded anything else than making a Unity project and then loading it to Visual Studio using Universal Windows Platform.

Comment: The link you provided is an article with a lot of steps, and it starts by referring to two other articles with even more steps. I assume you followed all steps in the suggested order. Exactly at what step did you get the error? Was there any relevant output or behavior prior to the error?

Comment: I haven't tried exactly this thing but very much similar and I am getting this error when I try to start the emulator.

Comment: [This forum thread](https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/226/cant-deploy-to-the-hololens-emulator) is a few years old but maybe it can give you some ideas on how to fix the problem. Seems you are not alone in having trouble with the emulator.

Comment: I went through this thread earlier also but nothing worked. I tried on the HoloLens emulator and everything is working on it. So, its probably an issue with emulator only.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the Troubleshooting section of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/using-the-hololens-emulator.  I suspect you're hitting an installation issue where XDE is installed to the wrong folder.  The documentation includes a solution for this.  Please let me know if this does not resolve the issue.